# What is the best approach to design a set of "guiding screens" for an android app?

Tags: android, animation, scroll

I need to design introduction walk-through screens when my app launches. It can be done by simple ViewPager or horizontal scroll view (?) but the additional requirements which are hindering me from using these are

1. A lot of animations on each screen
2. Animations will be bound to scroll position (i.e., current stage on an animation will be determined by how much user has scrolled, and it should roll back animation if user scrolls back without finish gesture)
3. Some items need to animate across different screens (e.g., There is a box on first screen, when user scrolls to the next screen, the box becomes larger without moving and a graph (a part of second screen) also comes into display under it)

I dont know if I explained the scenario well enough so please ask for clarification in comments. I need just a direction to control/approach/library.


Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend this library : [ShowCase](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)

In this way, you can make interactive tutorial and walkthrough your app.
You can also take this library and add some functionality.

Comment: Its more about walking user through controls of your app. I am more interested in showing what my app can do BEFORE the actual app loads.

Comment: Well, u can add some stub fragments and views to your viewpager, and add those view at start with showcase. You can always put your own animations etc. At last page, add button : go to the app. And solved problem :) U can load data from json stored in assets, and put as many custom animations, as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use viewpager, for each fragment you can use different animation inside that fragment, each fragment is independent from other views/fragments
You can use horizontal scroll view but it will take extra time and difficult to code

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a `ViewPager` has everything you need.